# Docker - Failed to ping backend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

When i turned on my Mac I am getting this [image] This window is not letting me select. When i try to uninstall the Docker from Mac Applications it says that Docker is still running. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

I am also having a similar issue, and wanted to force quit the app, so I tried <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>options</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>, but couldn't find the app in the options.

I finally solved the issue by killing the `docker` process using **Activity Monitor**.

Steps:

1. Search for activity monitor by pressing (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>), start typing `activity monitor`, then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. Go to search bar and type `docker`, you will see the `docker` process in red with (not responding)
3. Double click on the docker process
4. Click **Quit** and select **Force quit**.

Comment: this will help. https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-view-and-kill-processes-on-mac

Comment: This isn't a solution.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by removing Setting.json code from my local pc

```
$ pwd
$ cd ~/Library/Group\ Containers/

Group Containers$ ls -la | grep "group.com.docker"
Group Containers$ group.com.docker

Group Containers$ cd group.com.docker
group.com.docker $ cat settings.json

Group Containers $ rm -rf group.com.docker
```

Now run it again.

Answer (score 4):

`killall Docker` in terminal fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Kill the running process using the command `top | grep "Docker"` then get the `PID` and kill the PID using the command `kill <your_pid`.

Goto your root folder in your Finder make sure permissions for your user were `Read & Write` and also make sure that those permissions are were applied to items enclosed.

Try restarting the Docker and it should up and running